# Integration with no Differential?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to follow along with this example from *Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems* 11th edition page 10.

In this example, they describe the process of solving a simple first order ODE given by:

$$ \frac{dp}{dt} =\frac{p-900}{2} $$

It's example 1, so they didn't introduce the term "separable" yet, but the method they go about solving this seems very weird to me.

Normally, one would rewrite the equation as
$$
\frac{dp}{p-900} = \frac{1}{2}dt
$$
integrate both sides, exponente the resulting $\log$ and solve for $p$.

Instead, here's what they do:

1. Rewrite the equation as:
   $$
   \frac{dp/dt}{p-900} =\frac{1}{2}
   $$
2. Observe that $\frac{dp/dt}{p-900}$ is equal to $\frac{d}{dt}\log|p-900|$, and so therefore we have
   \begin{equation}
   \frac{d}{dt}\log|p-900| = \frac{1}{2}
   \tag{1}\label{1} 
   \end{equation}
3. Integrate both sides of the above to obtain:
   $$
   \log |p-900|=\frac{t}{2}+C
   $$
   And here is where I'm lost .... it seems like they multiplied both sides of equation \eqref{1} by $dt$, but then there is no differential on the LHS with respect to which we can integrate.

I've attached a screenshot of the relevant section for more context. The confusion is going from equation 7 to 8.
[image: Example one]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\log|p-900| = \frac{1}{2}
\end{equation}
$$d(\log |p-900|)=\frac12\,dt$$
$$\int d(\log |p-900|)=\int \frac12\,dt$$
$$\log |p-900|=\frac12t+C$$
The term $d(\log |p-900|)$ is a differential.

Comment: Got it. I guess it would look more normal if I substituted $z = \log|p-900|$, so the LHS would be $\int dz$. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying the integrating factor $e^{-\frac{1}{2} t}$, we get $(\frac{dp}{dt} - \frac{p}{2})e^{-\frac{1}{2}t} = -450 e^{-\frac{1}{2}t}$. Integrate both side, we obtain $p = 900 + ce^{\frac{1}{2}t}$